# SQL - update multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

How can I do in the following situation:

I would like to update 3 columns for example, in the same table:

### **QUERY**

```
UPDATE Table
SET x='XX', y='YY', z='ZZ'
WHERE x='1', y='1', z='1'
```

I tried this code but didn't worked.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're SQL in the where condition is wrong, you should use logical operators instead of commas:

```
UPDATE table
SET x = 'XX',
    y = 'YY', 
    z = 'ZZ'
WHERE x = '1' 
   AND y = '1' 
   AND z = '1'
```

You would only use commas to seperate fields you want to set. For the where clause, you would use your logical keywords such as AND, or, OR

Answer (score 1):

your query was wrong. it was like this

```
update Table set x='XX', y='YY', z='ZZ' where x='1' OR y='1' OR z='1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost got it right, but the syntax is different in the update part and in the where clause, try it like this:

```
update Table set x='XX', y='YY', z='ZZ' where x='1' and y='1' and z='1'
```

Comment: Alex, is this correct?
The UPDATE will happen only when all the 3 conditions are true.

Comment: Yes - it will only update if ````x y z```` are 1. From the OP it seems like he wants to perform this kind of query.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

Your where clause is wrong syntax `where x='1', y='1', z='1'`

change to:

```
UPDATE myTable 
  SET x='XX', y='YY', z='ZZ' 
 WHERE x='1' AND  y='1' AND z='1'
```

OR

```
UPDATE myTable 
   SET x='XX', y='YY', z='ZZ' 
 WHERE x='1' OR y='1' OR z='1'
```